# Use OSMDROID to display my server generated map tiles

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, osmdroid, openmaptiles

I am trying to display map tiles using osmdroid. but it is displaying blank screen.
This is my code:

```
map.setZ(100);
    map.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("", 12, 18, 256, ".png",
            new String[]{"https://storage.googleapis.com/brainpool/user-files/brainpoollicense/maptiles/PL53LY4K0EDYMX/"}) {
        @Override
        public String getTileURLString(long pMapTileIndex) {
            return getBaseUrl()
                    + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
                    + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
                    + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
                    + mImageFilenameEnding;
        }
    });

    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    GeoPoint startPoint;
    startPoint = new GeoPoint(151.2927108765, -32.779342448);
    mapController.setZoom(12F);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
    map.invalidate();
    createmarker();
```

This is output:
[image]

Also, note that i am getting this in output always:
`W/OsmDroid: Problem downloading MapTile: /12/1674/2 HTTP response: Not Found`

My question is when getTileURLString method is called? because it is called for the values which are taking wrong z/x/y which do not exist on the server.

Comment: `It is always taking wrong z/x/y ` Who? Aren't you supplying those values yourself? We cannot see what you ask.

Comment: getTileURLString is called automatically according to center and zoom level. I want to know how it is called by library.